# Is there a procedure to solve Diophantine Equations?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How would you go about solving a multivariable, non-linear Diophantine Equation?

Comment: It would be stunning if there were. But if there were, one could prove, for example, Fermat's Last Theorem with it.

Comment: @mixedmath: The general Fermat equation is an example of an *exponential Diophantine equation*. The Matiyasevich result is for ordinary Diophantine equations, no variables in the exponent. Undecidability of exponential diophantine equations was proved a number of years before Matiyasevich's result, by Davis-Putnam-Robinson.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By a famous result of [Matiyasevich,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Matiyasevich) there is no universal algorithm which, when fed any Diophantine equation, will determine whether or not that equation has a solution in integers.

Interestingly, it is still unknown whether there is an algorithm that will always determine whether or not a Diophantine equation has a solution in rationals.

For *quadratic* Diophantine equations, in any number of variables, there *is* an algorithm. For degree $4$ equations, it is known that there is not. The question for cubic equations is unresolved.

Comment: What is the name of the algorithm for quadratic Diophantines? Links please!

Comment: @faktor Although it is only for the two-variable case, you could start here: http://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM . As you can see it is a mixture of techniques depending on the discriminant.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks Eric! I really appreciate it...I am so fascinated by this stuff, I changed my username to diophantine! :D

Comment: There is stuff in Logical Number Theory (Smorynski). Lots of other sources. It is essentially an application of the Hasse Principle.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no general procedure. [This was Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem).

Comment: I have heard of Hilbert's tenth, but what I mean to ask is not whether an equation is solvable with integer solutions, but knowing that it has integer solutions, is there any method of attack that should be taken?